# Batch normalization update with boolean tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I know that using batch normalization in Tensorflow is a solved problem, but I ran into something I don't quite understand while adopting the code available to my needs.

**Problem**: It seems that when working with conditional branches the order you put the branches inside the cond() function matters.

I put together the following minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inpt = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1])
do_update = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.5)

def update():
    ema_assign = ema.apply([inpt])
    with tf.control_dependencies([ema_assign]):
        return tf.identity(ema.average(inpt))

def no_update():
    return ema.average(inpt)

run = tf.python.control_flow_ops.cond(do_update, update, no_update) # this works
# run = tf.python.control_flow_ops.cond(do_update, no_update, update) # this doesn't work
# run = tf.python.control_flow_ops.cond(tf.logical_not(do_update), no_update, update) # this doesn't work as well

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)

for _ in range(10):
    run_v = sess.run([run], feed_dict={do_update: True, inpt: [1.0]})
    print run_v[0]

run_v = sess.run([run], feed_dict={do_update: False, inpt: [1000.0]})
print run_v[0]
```

The first line *run = ...* is not a problem to tensorflow and for me that outputs (as expected):

```
[ 0.5]
[ 0.75]
[ 0.875]
[ 0.9375]
[ 0.96875]
[ 0.984375]
[ 0.9921875]
[ 0.99609375]
[ 0.99804688]
[ 0.99902344]
[ 0.99902344]
```

However, for the second and third line I get a ValueError:

```
ValueError: fn1 and fn2 must return the same number of results.
```

It seems like it's important that the fn1 branch is the one containing the Average update, but I have no clue why that makes sense. Any thoughts about that behavior?

Comment: Weird, What if you wrap ema in tf.identity?

Comment: When I use: `return tf.identity(ema.average(inpt))` it results in a different error message on the line just changed: `ValueError: None values not supported.`